# Which class of animals constitute the largest biomass?

Tags: zoology, environment

I found [here](http://www.sciencefocus.com/qa/what-animal-collectively-makes-largest-biomass-earth-0) that species-wise it is cow. But, collectively, insects may exceed even mammals. So, which class of animals constitutes the largest biomass?

Comment: Prokaryotes still rule the world. Bacterial and Archaeal biomass far exceeds any other class of living organism.

Comment: But prokaryotes are no animals.

Comment: according ot this, arthropods. https://www.weforum.org/agenda/2021/08/total-biomass-weight-species-earth the big kicker is krill, there is a LOT of rill in the ocean.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following from MarchHo's comment, I have not been able to find class-specific (in the formal sense) estimates, but if you meant 'class' in an informal sense, the following may be useful.

A nice infographic covering the relative biomass of all land mammals is [here](https://xkcd.com/1338/), and a full table for species groups (at the level of domesticated vertebrates, invertebrates, etc) is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRhRf.png) (reproduced below).

[image]

Short answer: amongst animals, invertebrates are where the mass is.

Comment: Don't invertebrates make up multiple phyla and not a single class though?

Comment: @MarchHo Good point. I read the question as 'group' in the informal sense, but that was based on the comments mentioning Kingdom-level groups, rather than the question itself.